# firefox disable/enable add-on in a specific page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm programming a system to work with in firefox, based on high end javascript.

The users sometimes uses add-ons that conflict with the system.

Is there a way i can control from my web-site to disable or enable specific firefox add-ons in a page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it inside an add-on, prior to Firefox 4 there was the **nsIExtensionManager** interface, starting with Firefox 4 there is the [AddonManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager) object

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, I wouldn't want sites I browse doing anything to my browser add-ons unless I said they could.

With things like Firebug you CAN detect them though and warn the user, then it's down to them to turn them off and not you.

And here's another thought...imagine me turning off your Adblock because my site doesn't work well with it ;)

Comment: That depends entirely on the add-on, there's no common interface exposed to your page otherwise you could harvest what addons people have installed etc.